# Adding Google Ads event snippet inside php command in header.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, google-ads-api

I'm trying to add a Google Ads event snippet to a confirmed booking on a hotel booking website. The website is running on [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/).

The snippet needs to sit inside the $ord array, which i've been told is like this:

```
if($ord['status'] == 'confirmed){

// your code

}
```

However when i try this in my header.php or functions.php file it crashed the site.

```
if($ord['status'] == 'confirmed){ 

<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-712937327/fA8JCJeerakBEO-e-tMC',
      'value': 1.0,
      'currency': 'GBP',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>


<?php } ?>
```

I'm expecting the code to track when the booking status is changed to 'confirmed'. The result i'm getting at the moment is the website just displays a white screen with the message 'this website is experiencing technical difficulties'

Comment: you need to close off PHP before doing a different language

Comment: you're also missing a closing quote after confirmed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php if($ord['status'] == 'confirmed) { ?> 

<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-712937327/fA8JCJeerakBEO-e-tMC',
      'value': 1.0,
      'currency': 'GBP',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've tried this but still get the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please check php error logs and tell us the error?